# Android: Let Parent View Handle On Click

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` that contains a few items: An `ImageView` and a few small `TextView`'s.
Functionally I want to have the same on click event fire when anything in the `RelativeLayout` is clicked.
Visually I want to see the background of the `RelativeLayout` change so that it shows the entire layout (or "item") is being clicked.

My problem is that every time I click on the `TextView`'s the on click doesn't propagate back to the parent view and so the background color doesn't change. How can I do this?

Comment: could you post your code to have big image about what you need

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ensuring you got no `OnClickListener` assigned to any of the childs of your `RelativeLayout` shall usually suffice for them to not receive clicks. Also check if you got no `android:clickable="true"` set by any chance for it. Then once you assing `OnClickListener` to your `RelativeLayout` it should get all the clicks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I had set a click event to see what items were getting clicked and it turns out that was forcing the text view to receive the click event (ignoring clickable="false").

Comment: thanks a lot brother, this was really bugging me. its very easy to neglect the presence of `android:clickable="true"`. removing this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

for some items that has internal OnClickListener and you cannot easily remove their implementation of OnClickListener like `SwitchComat`, you can set

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

on your parent layout. by adding this attribute to the parent view, non of the children will receive click events regardless of having onClickListener or not.

[more on descendantFocusability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626337/can-someone-explain-descendantfocusability-afterdescendants)