# Limit focus to only one fragment in a container with multiple added fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus

[image]I have multiple fragments which use the same container, and when a fragment is added over another, I want focus to be shifted only among the views in recently added fragment. I tried to solve it using onBackstackChangeListener() but it doesn't seem to work. As in the image I want focus only on the Pin Entry fragment but the focus is shifting to the "Enter" buttons on the fragment behind the Pin Entry Fragment as well.Please help.

Comment: Make topmost root of your fragments clickable in xml .

Comment: @ADM can you explain some more please ...

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around to this problem but it's not a real solution, Best answer will be marked as correct answer.

Work Around:
 Add Views around your layout that needs the focus to stay with in itself. For Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>
<View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/left_view"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/buyOrWatch"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/movie_buy_selector"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/buy"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/preview"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/movie_buy_selector"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/preview"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white" />
        </LinearLayout>

 <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/right_view"/>
```

I placed the layout with the textviews in between the two focusable views with 0dp width.
Now, in your fragment class, bind those Views ,then define a `focusChangeListener()` for those views. for example if `leftView` binds view with id `android:id="@+id/left_view"` and `buyOrWatch` with `TextView` having `android:id="@+id/buyOrWatch"`,then,

```
 leftView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    buyOrWatch.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
```

You can define similar focus change listeners for each views like above, then as long as the fragment is visible, focus stays with in the fragment. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewGroup viewGroup;//assign your viewGroup
viewGroup.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

This must Work
Reference from [Can someone explain descendantFocusability = afterDescendants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626337/can-someone-explain-descendantfocusability-afterdescendants/45522137)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using single container for all fragment then you need to set  topmost root of your fragments clickable. Otherwise fragment behind can grab the focus for clickable items. See the fragment layout below for example.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am afraid, this doesn't seem to work with my codes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thats maybe because your enter pin fragment is wrap_content . Make if fill the parent .

Comment: @NishanKhadka can you find a solution, I have same the problem