# How to clear focus from imageview in Recyclerview when loading image with glide?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I found an error (more likely bug) when load image with glide on Recyclerview. The problem is that when I load image from URL into an `imageview` on `recyclerview` item, `imageview` seem to have focus on it. Here is how it looks like : [imageview gained focus after load image with glide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGOzf.png)

This causes `recyclerview` scrolls by itself (I cant post a video). Is there any idea how to solve this? Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: Why did u need to focus on that?

Comment: i actually want to clear the focus

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

recyclerview.setFocusable(false);

Answer (score 0):

try setting the **isFocusable** to false forcefully while loading the image using Glide.
it's just a try maybe it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

That is because RecyclerView ALWAYS set:

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

so if you apply those attribute in your XML for a RecyclerView

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focudeableInTouchMode="false"
```

yo can also use **descendantFocusability** here is link for better understanding of
[Can someone explain descendantFocusability = afterDescendants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626337/can-someone-explain-descendantfocusability-afterdescendants)

and also add **android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"** to your recyclerView and try again